# .Net Core - does something like IConvertible<T> exist?

Tags: .net-core, interface, type-conversion, generic-interface

I want to define an interface that specifies a method signature that returns a concrete type (with no parameters.) So something like:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    ConcreteType GetConcreteType();
}
```

So that's fine, I can do that, but if I wanted to specify a compare-to-concrete-type method, I could define my interface as inheriting from the IComparable interface. Something like this:

```
interface MyInterface : IComparable<MyConcreteClass>
{
    // no method signature required bc signature defined in IComparable<T>
}
```

Is there a native SDK construct for this - an interface that defines a Convert method?

I expected to find an `IConvertible<T>` interface but it looks like `IConvertible` is about something else (At a glance, I think it defines signatures that will make your class work as a parameter to the Convert class like, something like this: `int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(MyClassThatImplementsIConvertible);`

I just wrote this interface that does what I want but I'm thinking something like this already exists, yes? no?

```
public interface IConvertibleTo<T>
{
    void ConvertTo(out T convertedObj);
}
```

I used an out parameter bc I couldn't figure out how a class would implement multiple types of this interface, so:
 `public MyClass: IConvertibleTo<ClassA>, IConvertibleTo<ClassB> { }`
without getting methods with the same signatures but different return types.

Comment: You can explicitly implement those two interfaces, don't use `out`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: I don't want a class that implements two interfaces, I want an interface that specifies that it must be able to convert itself to a different class.

The object I'm working with are a Dictionary<string, object> and a complex type with it's own methods, props, etc. I don't want one class that implements both, I just want to make sure that the dictionary can create the complex object instance (presumably from it's property values)